# Leaflet Search: cannot search for Point types

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I followed this repository [Leaflet Search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search)

and I want to combine search box, using polygons, polylines, and point.
for polygons and polylines is working fine. But not for points. The property Name does appear but, when I select it there is no response..

[image: error]

as you can see i got error when i find point

and if i find anothers likes Polylines or polygons, [image: the results was successfull]

```
<script src="data/us-states.js"></script>
    <script src="data/restaurant.geojson.js"></script>

var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 1, center: new L.latLng([37.8, -96]) });

    map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer

    var us_states = new L.GeoJSON(us_states, {
        style: function(feature) {
            return {color: feature.properties.color };
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
            marker.bindPopup('<h4 style="color:'+feature.properties.color+'">'+ feature.properties.name +'</h4>');
        }
    });

    map.addLayer(us_states);

    var restaurant = new L.GeoJSON(restaurant, {
        style: function(feature) {
            return {color: feature.properties.color };
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
            marker.bindPopup('<h4 style="color:'+feature.properties.color+'">'+ feature.properties.name +'</h4>');
        }
    });

    map.addLayer(restaurant);

    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
        layer: L.featureGroup([us_states,restaurant]),
        propertyName: 'name',
        marker: false,
        moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
            var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
            map.setView(latlng, zoom); 
        }
    });

    searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
        e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});
        if(e.layer._popup)
            e.layer.openPopup();

    }).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {

        featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
        }); 
    });

    map.addControl( searchControl );
```

maybe someone can help me?

this error notice :

> Uncaught TypeError: latlng.layer.getBounds is not a function
>       at e.moveToLocation [as _moveToLocation] (geojson-layer.html:63)
>       at e.showLocation (leaflet-search.js:893)
>       at e._handleSubmit (leaflet-search.js:856)
>       at e. (leaflet-search.js:398)
>       at HTMLLIElement.r (leaflet.js:5)

Comment: Please always post error messages in plain text so that others can search for it. Edit your post please and add the error message there.

Comment: @Stefan check new update

Comment: You mention Name but in code say name, make sure they are the same case in code and data. Second issue was fit bounds may not work with one point, I usually put points into a group layer and fit bounds to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problematic code seems to be mixture of two Leaflet Search examples: [geojson-layer](https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/geojson-layer.html) and [multiple-layers](https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/multiple-layers.html).

First problem is that there was some renaming done but not completely. Original layer `featuresLayer` is now `us_states`, but in `search:collapsed` event handler there is still old name.

The secend problem is that in `restaurant` geojson features have `Point` geometry and have to be treated differently from `us_states` geojson, where features have `Polygon` geometry.

Difference has to accounted for in layer definition (`onEachFeature` for polygons, `pointToLayer` for points), in `moveToLocation` option of search control definition and in `search:locationfound` event handler.

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 1, center: new L.latLng([37.8, -96]) });

map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer

var us_statesLayer = new L.GeoJSON(us_states, {
        style: function(feature) {
            return {color: feature.properties.color };
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
            marker.bindPopup('<h4 style="color:'+feature.properties.color+'">'+ feature.properties.name +'</h4>');
        }
    });

var restaurantLayer = new L.GeoJSON(restaurant, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {
                icon: L.divIcon({
                    className: feature.properties.amenity,
                    iconSize: L.point(16, 16),
                    html: feature.properties.amenity[0].toUpperCase(),
                })
            }).bindPopup(feature.properties.amenity+'<br><b>'+feature.properties.name+'</b>');
        }
});

var allLayers = L.layerGroup([
    us_statesLayer,
    restaurantLayer
])

map.addLayer(allLayers);

var lastStateLayerFound = null;

var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
    layer: allLayers,
    propertyName: 'name',
    marker: false,
    moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
        var zoom;
        if (latlng.layer.feature.geometry.type == 'Polygon') {
          zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
          lastStateLayerFound = latlng.layer;
          }
        else {
          lastStateLayerFound = null;
          zoom = 15;
        }
        map.setView(latlng, zoom);
    }
});

searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
    if (e.layer.feature.geometry.type == 'Polygon')
      e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});       
    if(e.layer._popup)
        e.layer.openPopup();

}).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {
    if (lastStateLayerFound) {
      us_statesLayer.resetStyle(lastStateLayerFound);
    }
});

map.addControl(searchControl);
```